# Prefill Sudoku Grid with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backtracking, sudoku

I am writing a little Sudoku game with plain JS.
Now I am struggling with my code. I saw some examples but I am not able to adapt my code like other ones. Maybe my idea is wrong.
My main problem is the recursive call of the fill function. I am not sure when to call it again and when to return booleans.
I tried some different approaches but I ran into endlessloops or a partly filled grid.

```
function fillGrid(grid) {

    // Run through grid to get next 0 to fill
    let filled = grid.every((row, rowIndex) => {
        // Row contains 0?
        let colIndex = row.indexOf(0);
        if (colIndex !== -1) {
            let randNumb = randomNumberBetween(1, 9);
            // Set random number where first 0 is found
            grid[rowIndex][colIndex] = randNumb;

            // Check validity
            let gridValid = gridIsValid(grid);

            // When valid continue with the new set number
            if (gridValid) {
                return fillGrid(grid);
            } else {
                // When not valid, reset number and have another try
                grid[rowIndex][colIndex] = 0;
                return fillGrid(grid);
            }
        }
    });

    return filled;
}
```

The function takes a prefilled grid with 0 in each Position and should fill the whole Grid with fitting numbers.
Other examples which I saw are iterating the number 1 - 9 and track the current col and row on each call of the function. I prefer to set immediatley a random number and calculate the next field.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

First of all, your `every` callback does not execute a `return` statement when there is no zero in the first row, and so it will be considered falsy. As a consequence, `every` will never visit the second row. You need to `return true` when there is no zero in the current row, so that `every` will proceed with the next row.

Once you have fixed that, you'll very likely get into an infinite recursion loop. Let's say your algorithm has filled the grid up to this point:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 1 2 3 . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
```

On the next free cell there is no possible value we can put: the values 1 to 6 are already used in the second row, and the three remaining values are already used in the 3x3 block in the top-right corner.

This means that your code will get stuck in this part:

```
            } else {
                // When not valid, reset number and have another try
                grid[rowIndex][colIndex] = 0;
                return fillGrid(grid);
            }
```

The recursive call will be made over and over again, only to find that again the grid is not valid, and so another recursive call follows... until you hit the stack limit.

What is missing is backtracking. You do have the "backtracking" where you undo the last move, but there is no backtracking to a *previously* put value, in a previous cell.

You need to detect that you have tried all 9 values for a certain cell and didn't have success with any of them. When that happens you need to replace the *previously* put value (even though that action did not lead to an obviously invalid grid). This backtracking may need to go back multiple levels...

One way to correct this, is to create a random order of the numbers 1 to 9 and then try them in that order. Now you can know when none of them worked and can do `return false`. This will trigger backtracking.

Here is your code adapted with that idea. I added a `gridIsValid` implementation (which may be different from yours, but does what it needs to do):

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

function range(a, b) {
    return Array.from({length: b - a + 1}, (_, i) => i + a);
}

function gridIsValid(grid) {
    function column(colIndex) {
        return grid.map(row => row[colIndex]); 
    }

    function block(blockIndex) {
        const colIndex = (blockIndex % 3) * 3;
        const rowIndex = Math.floor(blockIndex / 3) * 3;
        return grid.slice(rowIndex, rowIndex + 3).flatMap(row => row.slice(colIndex, colIndex + 3));
    }

    function groupIsValid(group) {
        group = group.filter(Boolean);
        return new Set(group).size === group.length;
    }
    
    return [
        ...grid,
        ...grid.map((_, i) => column(i)),
        ...grid.map((_, i) => block(i))
    ].every(groupIsValid);
}

function fillGrid(grid) {
    // Run through grid to get next 0 to fill
    const row = grid.find((row) => row.includes(0));
    if (!row) return true; // The grid has been filled.
    const colIndex = row.indexOf(0);
    // Loop over the 9 possible values we can put, in random order
    for (let randNumb of shuffle(range(1, 9))) {
        // Set random number where first 0 is found
        row[colIndex] = randNumb;
        // Check validity: When valid continue with the new set number
        if (gridIsValid(grid) && fillGrid(grid)) return true; // Found!: get out of recursion
        // When not valid, reset number and have another try (iteration)
        row[colIndex] = 0;
    }
    // All possible values for this cell failed... so backtrack!
    return false;
}

// Demo run:
const grid = Array.from({length: 9}, () => Array(9).fill(0));
fillGrid(grid);
for (const row of grid) console.log(...row);
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?